# Define true or false if in array two equal elements are present

Tags: php, arrays

Hi excuse my stupid question, but I am having troubles in finding the way to return true or false in a function that go through an array like the following one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1389
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1389
        ),

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14568
        ),

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14568
        )

)
```

I should be able to return `true` or `false` if in the array two equal elements are present or not. For example in the example array I should be able to return `true`, as 1389 and 14568 are both present.

On the opposite, if the array is made like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1389
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1389
        ),
)
```

the output should then be `false`

I tried to set the cycle as this, but obviously it doesn't work!

```
$products_id_array []= array( $product_id); // my array
$count = count($products_id_array);

$products = $products_id_array[0][0];//set the first term of teh array
$i=0;
while ($i<$count) {
  if ( $products_ids[$i][0] == $products)
  {
      $products = $products_ids[$i][0];
      $mixed_products = false;
  }
  else
  {
      $mixed_products = true;
  }
  $i++;
}
return $mixed_products;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `array_diff` & `array_intersect` functions:

```
$arr1 = [[1389], [1389], [14568], [14568]];
$arr2 = [[1389], [1389]];
$arr3 = [3, 3, 4, 4, 5 ];

function checkDoubleDuplicate(array $argArray) {
  $iflag = 0;
  $arrayUnique = array_unique($argArray, SORT_REGULAR);
  foreach ($arrayUnique as $key => $value) {
    $occuranceCount = count(array_intersect($argArray, array($value)));
    if ($occuranceCount == 2)
      $iflag++;
  }
  if (2 == $iflag)
    return TRUE;
  else
    return FALSE;
}

echo checkDoubleDuplicate($arr3) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

The only thing you'd better do is to convert your complicated/redundant array(using array for every single value, thus making memory/code complicated) to a simple form like `$arr3`. I've suggested solution with this *ToDo* in mind

Comment: Thanks, this solution has worked perfectly! I riolved my starting array as you sggested (i.e. I created a simple array from my multidimensional array) and then applied your function. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) function. Example:

```
$array1 = array(
        array(5),
        array(10),
        array(15),
        array(77),
        array(100)
    );
    $array2 = array(
        array(10),
        array(15)
    );

function udiffMultiDem($a, $b)
{
    return $a[0] - $b[0];
}

$diff = array_udiff($array1,$array2, 'udiffMultiDem'); //will contain elements that exist in $array1 and not in $array2

$cotainSameTwoValuesFlag = (count($array1)  - count($diff)) == 2;
var_dump($cotainSameTwoValuesFlag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = [[1389], [1389], [14568], [14568]];

$o = [];
array_walk($array, function($v) use(&$o)
{
    $o[$v[0]] = 0;
});
$result = array_keys($o);
$result = array_map(function($v){return [$v];}, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

and the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(1389)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(14568)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a one-line solution but does the work you want.

```
$myArray = array(
'0'=>array(1389),
'1'=>array( 1389),
'2'=>array(14568),
'3'=>array(14568)
);
$count=0;
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {
if($key>=1 && ($key%2)==true){ // key must be >=1 and even number to get output when a pair is checked
if($myArray[$key]==$myArray[$key-1]){
$count++;
}
if($count>1){
echo "True";
} else {
echo "False";
}
}
}
```

output is `False True`

Check it out in [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fb79c43cfbb2821ce70252a8fd75b209800623c)